# How to update "Lookup column" values from csv to Sharepoint Online using Powershell Script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, lookup-column, powershell-script

I have a Parent list called country and the child list where I want my values updated is call Continents.
the lookup filed name in Continents is "Country". Any help will be greatly appreciated!!
can someone please share the code.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? This forum is for help but not to provide copy paste code.

Comment: Hi, Yes i did try alot of solutions but nothing seems to work. the links that you gave are direct updates. I am looking for adding the lookup value from my excel to SPO list.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can easily find many examples.

Here are some scripts for your reference:

[https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-update-lookup-field.html#:~:text=PnP%20PowerShell%20to%20Set%20Lookup,of%20the%20parent%20lookup%20item](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-powershell-to-update-lookup-field.html#:%7E:text=PnP%20PowerShell%20to%20Set%20Lookup,of%20the%20parent%20lookup%20item).

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef8e8806-6d03-40e6-be4c-f98b89974941/how-do-i-set-the-value-of-a-lookup-field-with-powershell?forum=sharepointdevelopment